# Google Cloud End Point Error: Process exited before success message

Tags: android, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I am facing this error when I run the appengineStart task.

[print of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0Epr.png)

The error says: “com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.cloudsdk.internal.process.ProcessRunnerException: Process exited before success message”

I searched on Google, but wasn’t able to find a solution.

Here is the full error log:

```
10:33:08: Executing task 'appengineStart'...

Executing tasks: [appengineStart]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Gradle now uses separate output directories for each JVM language, but this 
build assumes a single directory for all classes from a source set. This 
behaviour has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0
:backend:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:backend:processResources NO-SOURCE
:backend:classes UP-TO-DATE
:backend:endpointsDiscoveryDocs UP-TO-DATE
:backend:_zipDiscoveryDocs UP-TO-DATE
:backend:war UP-TO-DATE
:backend:explodeWar UP-TO-DATE
:backend:assemble UP-TO-DATE
:backend:appengineStart
Warning: Google App Engine Java 7 runtime is deprecated.
Warning: See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/deprecations/java7
ago 23, 2018 10:33:24 AM java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences <init>
ADVERT?NCIA: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs 
at root 0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.
ago 23, 2018 10:33:25 AM 
com.google.appengine.tools.development.SystemPropertiesManager 
setSystemProperties
INFORMA??ES: Overwriting system property key 
'java.util.logging.config.file', value 
'C:\Users\igor\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud- `sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\java\config\sdk\logging.properties' with value 'WEB-INF/logging.properties' from 'C:\Users\igor\ud-exercises\ud867\FinalProject\backend\build\exploded-backend\WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml'`

************************************************
Could not open the requested socket: Address already in use: bind
Try overriding --address and/or --port.
Exception in thread "wait-for-process-exit-and-output-handlers" com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.api.AppEngineException: Non zero exit: 2
    at com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.cloudsdk.process.NonZeroExceptionExitListener.onExit(NonZeroExceptionExitListener.java:30)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.cloudsdk.internal.process.DefaultProcessRunner.syncRun(DefaultProcessRunner.java:211)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.cloudsdk.internal.process.DefaultProcessRunner.access$200(DefaultProcessRunner.java:38)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.cloudsdk.internal.process.DefaultProcessRunner$3.run(DefaultProcessRunner.java:223)
:backend:appengineStart FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':backend:appengineStart'.
>



com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.cloudsdk.internal.process.ProcessRunnerException: Process exited before success message

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

    BUILD FAILED in 16s
    6 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 5 up-to-date
    10:33:26: Task execution finished 'appengineStart'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Could not open the requested socket: Address already in use: bind` indicates that you either previously started a dev server and it didn't exit properly, or you have another process using the same port. You need to kill the offending process (or restart your computer, which has the same effect) or [change the port on which your dev server runs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/gradle-reference#appenginerun). Essentially, add the following to your gradle file, changing the port as necessary:

```
appengine.run.port = 8888
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Restart the computer didn't work. This is the first time i'm setting a google cloud end point up. So, how do I change the port and how do I know if there is something preventing me from use the default 8080? Is there any comprehensive guide or tutorial to make my first time easier?

Comment: See the link I posted. In particular, in your gradle file, you can try adding `appengine.run.port = 8888`. As for seeing what ports are being used, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198/how-can-you-find-out-which-process-is-listening-on-a-port-on-windows).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Changing the port, adding appengine.run.port = 8888 to gradle file, worked for me. I think it would be a good thing if you edit your first answer putting this command, so it will be easier to find.